# jquery click bind on div effecting textbox residing within

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div class="infoBox2 blackBoxHover">
    <h2>direct Link: </h2> 
    <input class="fileInput" type="text" id="directlinkText" name="directlinkText" />
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$('#directlinkText').parent('div').click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

The thing is I want to see test when I click anywhere on the div EXCEPT for if I click on the input that's within it. 
Right now clicking the textbox input also fires the div's click event

how do I fix this?

Comment: Read this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/domtricks2/

Comment: That's because the `<input>` is part of the `<div>`. You'll have to put in a `click` handler on the `<input>` that kills the propagation of the click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#directlinkText').parent('div').click(function (e) {
        if(e.target.id === "directlinkText"){
            return;
        }
        alert('test');
 });
```

Comment: You could also check for: `if(e.target === this)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your input is inside div. Attach event to your text box and then stop event propagation.

```
$('#directlinkText').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop event propagation.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the propagation of the `click` event when it originates from the `input` elements like this:

```
$('#directlinkText').click(false).parent('div').click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

This returns `false` for the click event directly on the `#directlinkText` element. Which in a jQuery event handler is the same as calling: `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. If you just wanted to stop the propagation and not prevent the default behavior then you could use:

```
$('#directlinkText').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}).parent('div').click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```