# Click event on div except for textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using Jquery Flip to create a flash card game. I have the following:

```
<div id="card" style="width: 300px;">
    <div class="front" style=" height:200px; width:200px; background-color:#d9edf7;">
    </div>

    <div class="back" style=" height:200px; width:200px; background-color: #eee;">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is held within a partial view called `_SafmedDialog`

When I click on the front div it will check the answer, and when you click on the back div it will fetch the next question.

```
$("#card").flip();

$('div.front').click(function () {        
    CheckAnswer($('#safmedId').val(), $('#Answer').val());
})

$('div.back').click(function () {

    GetQuestion();
})
```

I want it to only go and get the next question if you click anywhere on the div apart from the textbox which resides within `_SafmedQuestion`

```
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Answer, new { id = "answer" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SafmedId, new { id = "safmedId" })


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Answer').focus();
    })

</script>
```

I've found this question: [jquery click bind on div effecting textbox residing within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318943/jquery-click-bind-on-div-effecting-textbox-residing-within)

However when I change my javascript to this:

```
$('div.front').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id === "Answer") {
        return;
    }
    CheckAnswer($('#safmedId').val(), $('#Answer').val());
})
```

The card still flips and executes the `CheckAnswer` method, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it due to the `e.target.id` being a capital "A", but the id is lowercase?

Comment: just tried this, still flips the card and tries to check the answer with no input

Comment: Can you debug it and see what the e.target.id is when you click the answer button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your click events, make sure to grab the event argument and invoke the events [stopPropagation method](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiYyrWo79jHAhXBdT4KHRQnDP0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fevent.stoppropagation%2F&usg=AFQjCNH6EuKnUdIUCU8OBNK-5KApY-umkg&sig2=olr1FTviSgFOzjcYxLut4Q&bvm=bv.101800829,d.cWw)

**UPDATE:**
To keep your click event from bubbling to its parent, do:

```
$('div.front').click(function (e) {
  if (e.target.id === "Answer") {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
  CheckAnswer($('#safmedId').val(), $('#Answer').val());
});
```

Comment: if I do this the card wont flip no matter where I click

Comment: This is due to 'event bubbling' which javascript calls all parent code. .stopPropagation(); will stop the bubbling effect http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Im shooting from the hip a bit... it'd be helpful to have a little more of your js and html...


but try:

$('div.front').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id === "Answer") {
        **e.stopPropagation();**
        **return false;**
    }
    CheckAnswer($('#safmedId').val(), $('#Answer').val());
})

Comment: Nice one, your comment worked, updated your answer and I will mark as the correct one.

Comment: @selectDistinct will you mark this as the answer?  thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all familiar with MVC but wouldn't

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Answer, new { id = "answer" })
```

produce an id with the lowercase 'answer' And all of your javascript is looking for the uppercase 'Answer'. They are not ===.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's failing because the click function will always be on the `.front` div. You probably want to turn on the click handler after they have clicked the answer div like so:

```
$( "#answer" ).click(function() {
  $('div.front').click(function () {        
    CheckAnswer($('#safmedId').val(), $('#Answer').val());
  });
});
```

This should only check the answer after they have clicked inside `#answer`.

## Edit

Sorry, I looked at your last code block and got mixed up with what you wanted. You want the code to only go after they click an answer, so put both functions inside the answer click:

```
$( "#answer" ).click(function() {
  $('div.front').click(function () {        
    CheckAnswer($('#safmedId').val(), $('#Answer').val());
    $("#card").flip();
  });
  $('div.back').click(function () {
    GetQuestion();
  }); 
});
```

This will make it so that nothing happens until they click an answer. Then if they click the `.front` div, it will check the answer and flip the card (assuming the card flip thing, move to your liking). And then if they click the `.back` div it will go to the next question only after they've selected an answer.

Comment: #Answer is the textbox, i have inspected the box in dev tools and even though im setting the id as answer it comes through as Answer, must be MVC related. I dont want to check the answer if they click the textbox, only if they click on an area around the text box, so anywhere in the div.front UNLESS they click inside #Answer

Comment: @selectDistinct edited my answer. Realized I got mixed up with what you wanted lol.

Comment: The textbox #Answer is where they type the answer, once they have typed their answer, I want them to click off the textbox and then and only then will the card flip and check, if they click on the textbox i want it to do nothing

Comment: Putting the click handlers inside the #Answer click handler won't automatically run the other click handlers. I will "enable" them. So, they must click in the #Answer textbox to "enable" the other two click handlers. Once they're enabled, the user must actually click those divs to "run" the functions. Is that what you wanted?